# Type combination not properly detected

Tags: typescript

I am facing an issue with some typescript combination, and can't find the proper way to write it. I submitted a bug on typescript project, but I was directed here (https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43334).

```
type StructuredParameters<T extends unknown[]> = { param: T }
type AsDispatchArgs<T extends unknown[]> = T | [StructuredParameters<T>];
type AsDispatchArg<T extends unknown[]> = T[0] | StructuredParameters<T>;

interface A{
     dispatch( param: StructuredParameters<unknown[]>): void
     dispatch( ...params: unknown[]): void
     dispatch( param: AsDispatchArg<unknown[]>, ...params: unknown[]): void;
}

interface B extends A
{
    dispatch(...args:[string,string,number]):void
}
```

Any idea why typescript throws an compilation error on B ?

Comment: It's the first condition that's the issue.  The other two are fine.

Comment: If you have a value of type `A`, you can call `dispatch()` in three different ways. If you have a value of type `B`, what do you want... to able to call `dispatch()` it in *four* different ways?  Or just *one*?  Or something else?  Or do you just want to know why you get the error on `B`?  By the way, this code has problems besides the error on `B`, and so it does not seem to be a [mcve]. This may be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) and you will not be happy even if you get an answer to your question as stated. What, specifically, are you trying to do?

Comment: I just want all of the signatures possible. I have slightly altered the design to make it as small as possible. In my concrete example, A is a class, B does not extend A, but I have a variable declared as A & B. My goal is to have intellisense and auto complete for known functions, but for unknown, have the fallback to A overloads.